# Constrain position of Dojo FloatingPane

Tags: dojo

I have a dojox.layout.FloatingPane (as a custom dijit) which can be positioned anywhere within its enclosing div. My problem is that the user can potentially drag the FloatingPane completely outside of its container and be unable to retrieve it. Is there any easy way to force the FloatingPane to remain entirely visible at all times?

Here's my code:

```
dojo.provide("ne.trim.dijits.SearchDialog");

dojo.require("dijit._Widget");
dojo.require("dijit._Templated");
dojo.require("dojox.layout.FloatingPane");

dojo.declare("ne.trim.dijits.SearchDialog", [dijit._Widget, dijit._Templated], {

templateString: dojo.cache("ne.trim.dijits", "templates/SearchDialog.html"),
initialised:false,
floatingPane: null,

postCreate: function() {
    this.init();
},

init: function() {
    console.debug("SearchDialog.init()", "start");
    if ( this.initialised === false ) {
        this.createSearchDialog();
    }
    //ne.trim.AppGlobals.searchDialog = this;
    console.debug("SearchDialog.init()", "end");        
},

createSearchDialog: function() {
    var node = dojo.byId('searchbox');  
    floatingPane = new dojox.layout.FloatingPane({
         title: "A floating pane",
         resizable: true, dockable: true, constrainToContainer: true,
         style:   "position:absolute;top:100;right:100;width:400px;height:300px;z-index:100",
    }, node );

    this.initialised=true;

    floatingPane.startup();
}

});
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First of all, see the working example at jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/phusick/3vTXW/

And now some explanation;) The DnD functionality of `FloatingPane` is achieved via `dojo.dnd.Moveable` class instantialized in pane's `postCreate` method. To constrain the movement of the `FloatingPane` you should use one of these moveables instead:

- `dojo.dnd.parentConstainedMoveable` - to constrain by a DOM node
- `dojo.dnd.boxConstrainedMoveable`  - to constrain by co-ordinates: {l: 10, t: 10, w: 100, h: 100}
- `dojo.dnd.constrainedMoveable` - to constrain by co-ordinates calculated in a provided function

For more details see aforementioned [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/phusick/3vTXW/).

According to documentation you should call `destroy()` on `Moveable` instance to remove it, but as `FloatingPane`'s original `Moveable` is not assigned to any object property, I do not destroy it, I just instantiate one of those three `moveables` on the same DOM node in a subclass:

```
var ConstrainedFloatingPane = dojo.declare(dojox.layout.FloatingPane, {

    postCreate: function() {
        this.inherited(arguments);
        this.moveable = new dojo.dnd.move.constrainedMoveable(this.domNode, {
            handle: this.focusNode,
            constraints: function() {
                return dojo.coords(dojo.body());
            }
        });
    }

});
```

Now you can use `ConstainedFloatingPane` instead of `dojox.layout.FloatingPane`:

```
var floatingPane = new ConstrainedFloatingPane({
    title: "A Constrained Floating Pane",
    resizable: true
}, searchboxNode);
```

Comment: That's a great response phusick and just what I need. Many thanks!

Comment: A great question too! It finally made me to dig deeper into Dojo's DnD.

Comment: There is an issue with this, because you can resize your ConstrainedFloatingPane to be bigger than the actual constrained area. Is there a way to fix that?