# Constrain a moveable object in Dojo

Tags: dojo

First of all there is a question/answer for this already:
[Constrain position of Dojo FloatingPane](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9445868/constrain-position-of-dojo-floatingpane)
http://jsfiddle.net/phusick/3vTXW/

I used the above to create movable panes and it was working first. Then I created a module with the object and the constrain doesn't work any more, I can move the object out of the window.

I placed the following code in a separate module:

```
define(["dojo/_base/declare", "dojo/dnd/move", "dojox/layout/FloatingPane"],     function(declare, move, FloatingPane){
return declare("dashboardFloatingPane", FloatingPane, {

constructor: function() {
        this.inherited(arguments);
        this.moveable = new dojo.dnd.move.boxConstrainedMoveable(
            this.domNode, {
                handle: this.focusNode,
                constraints: {
                        l: 0,
                        t: 20,
                        w: 500,
                        h: 500                            
                    },
                within: true
            }
        );                            
    } 
});
});
```

Then I create the object here:

```
        require(["dojo/dnd/move", "dojox/layout/FloatingPane", "dashboardFloatingPane", "dojo/domReady!"],
        function(move, FloatingPane, dashboardFloatingPane) {

            var widgetNode1 = dojo.byId("widget1");

            var floatingPane = new dashboardFloatingPane({
                title: "A floating pane",
                resizable: true,
                dockable: false,
                style: "position:absolute;top:40px;left:40px;width:160px;height:100px;"       
                }, widgetNode1);

            floatingPane.startup();
        });
```

But again, I can move the pane wherever I want, even outside the box that was set. Any ideas please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to override the `postCreate` method, not the `contructor` in the `dojox/layout/FloatingPane` class.

The reason is that the original class sets `this.moveable` to it's own moveable type, so to override it, you have to reassign it to your constrained moveable afterward.

Try this:

```
define(["dojo/_base/declare", "dojo/dnd/move", "dojox/layout/FloatingPane"], function(declare, move, FloatingPane){
  return declare("dashboardFloatingPane", FloatingPane, {

    postCreate: function() {
      this.inherited(arguments);
      this.moveable = new dojo.dnd.move.boxConstrainedMoveable(
        // snip...
      );
    } 
  });
});
```