# Use Dojo boxConstrainedMoveable to constrain movable div to window

Tags: dojo

I have a div, to which I applied Dojo dojo/dnd/Moveable. But, I'd like to prevent the user from dragging the div offscreen. So, I think I need to implement dojo/dnd/move/boxConstrainedMoveable.

I'm starting with this:

```
var dnd = new Moveable(this.domNode, {
   'handle': this.titleNode
});
```

There's a similar SO question here:
[Constrain a moveable object in Dojo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11842106/constrain-a-moveable-object-in-dojo). Applying that answer, I get something like this:

```
var dnd = new move.boxConstrainedMoveable(
   'handle': this.titleNode
    constraints: {
        l: 0,
        t: 20,
        w: 500,
        h: 500                            
    },
    within: true    
);
```

But, I just can't understand how the bounding box works. I simply want the div to stay inside the window. I've tried implementing a few things with the window box, the div's margin box. Nothing's worked, and all I've made is a big mess.

I read the docs here:
   http://dojotoolkit.org/api/?qs=1.9/dojo/dnd/move.boxConstrainedMoveable

Has anyone done this with Dojo? I'd be very appreciate of an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I looked up some old code I have and I did implement this type of movable once. This was written against Dojo 1.7, so things may have changed in 1.9. Fiddle demonstration: https://jsfiddle.net/4ev1daqr/26/

The main difference between your attempted solution and this is that the `constraints` property in the `moveable` needs to be a *function* rather than a static bounding box.  When using the `boxConstrainedMoveable` module, the static bounding box should be assigned to a `box` property, rather than the `constraints` property.

This is actually a nice design, IMHO, because it allows the constraints to react to changes in application state, e.g. hiding a sidebar or moving a splitter, but it does make the simple case a bit more difficult to get working.

```
define(["dojo/_base/declare",
    "dojo/dnd/move",
    "dojo/dom",
    "dojo/_base/window",
    "dojo/dom-style",
    "dojo/dom-geometry",
    ],
    function (declare, move, dom, win, domStyle, domGeom) {

return declare( "my/dnd/move/BodyConstrainedMoveable", [move.constrainedMoveable], {

    markupFactory: function(params, node){
        return new this(node, params);
    },

    constructor: function(node, params) {
        // Constrain the node to be within the body
        this.constraints = function() {
            var n = win.body(),
                s = domStyle.getComputedStyle(n),
                mb = domGeom.getMarginBox(n, s);

            if ( this.node ) {
                var menubox = domGeom.getMarginBox(this.node);

                mb.w -= menubox.w;
                mb.h -= menubox.h;
            }

            return mb;
        };
    }
})});
```

Comment: This is **great**. I'm using CMV, which has a collapsible sidebar, so, the dynamic bounding box is needed. I think I can set the bounding node to be the map node. But, my draggable contains a nested IFRAME (for Pictometry). And, that's causing a lot flakiness. Actually, the dijit/dialog docs say that nested IFRAME is not supported, because if this "focus trap". That's why I didn't use dialog. I haven't tried it with FloatingPanel, though. Maybe that will help.

Comment: Also, I like this design of extending constrainedMoveable, rather than passing in parameters. Much cleaner.